# Custom getters in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, getter

I have a MailingList model that has_may :people

For most of my application, I only want to get people that are active

So `@mailing_list.people` should only return people that are active

In my model, I can't do

```
def people
  self.people.find_all{ |p| !p.activated_at.nil? }
end
```

because that keeps calling itself.  What is the ruby/rails way to automatically filter the people.  Another possible issue is that I think self.people returns an array of active record objects where `self.people.find_all...` will return an array.  This will cause some of my code to break.  It's easy fixes but is there a way to return active record objects?  It would be nice to have the option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also filter at the association level.

```
has_many :people, :conditions => {:activated => true}
```

Comment: i think this is what i'm looking for under 2 conditions.  the first is that i want to be able to override the filter when necessary.  the second is that i need to check if "activated_at" is "not NULL" so there needs to be a way to do that. thanks!

Comment: OK i was able to accomplish the is "not NULL" requirement.  the only remaining issue is how do skip the filter?

Answer (score 6):

This is a perfect example for a named scope:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  named_scope :active, :conditions => 'activated_at is not null'
end
```

Then just call it:

```
# equivalent to Person.find(:all, :conditions => 'activated_at is not null')
@active_people = Person.active
```

Comment: You can chain named scopes too. If you have created one called :recent that only selects users created in the last week, you can call Person.active.recent to get all recently activated people.

Comment: 2 issues here.  One is that I want to call this on an instance, like @mailing_list.people.  The other is that I would rather not have to say ".active" since I will always be asking for active people. With that being said, there must be a way to override that restriction for when I want to look at inactive users (like on an administrator interface)

Comment: Not sure what's wrong with being explicit in calling Person.active, but your other option would be to use default_scope :conditions => 'activated_at is not null'. Then you could do Person.all and get only actives. Personally, I don't think that's a good idea though.

Comment: the issue is that i only want people that belong to a mailing list. Person.active would get ALL active people.  i need mailing_list.people

Answer (score 0):

You can used the standard find method or a dynamic finder.  Your find might read as follows:

people.find(:all, :conditions => "activated_at = nil")
OR
people.find_all(:conditions => "activated_at = nil")

A dynamic version of this might read as:

people.find_by_activated_at(nil)